# setTimeout() function is not executed properly

Tags: node.js

I have to send an SMS 15 minutes before the appointment is there. I have written the code, but it is called at the time of execution itself. Is there any other method or how do I solve this?

"RP.remindePatient" is the function that has to be called 15 minutes before the appointment time.

```
sendApptConf(s) {

    var number = Phone;
    var msg = urlencode("Hello " );

    var smsData = 'username=' + username + '&hash=' + hash + '&sender=' + sender + '&numbers=' + number + '&message=' + msg;
    var options = {

        host: 'api.textlocal.in',
        path: '/send?' + smsData
    };

    var callback;
    console.log(options);
    callback = function (response) {
        var str = '';

        // Another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("new Data received")
            str += chunk;
            console.log(str);
        });

        // The whole response has been received, so we just print it out here.
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str);
        });
    }

    http.request(options, callback).end();
    // Send SMS using Textlocal DONE

    const convertTime = consultDate + ' ' + consultTime;

    var d = new Date(convertTime);
    var ms = d.getTime();
    var milliLess15 = ms - (15 * 60 * 1000);

    console.log(milliLess15);

    setTimeout(function () {

        console.log("I should be called after some delay")
        RP.remindePatient(userPhone, patientName, drName, consultMode, consultDate, consultTime, transId, email, paymentDetails);

    }, milliLess15);
```

Comment: What do you mean with time of execution itself?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the variable after timeout. Just put in:

```
setTimeout(function () {
console.log("I should be called after some delay")
       RP.remindePatient(userPhone, patientName, drName, consultMode, consultDate, consultTime, transId, email, paymentDetails);

     }, 900000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small issue in your logic. As you would already know, `setTimeout(function () {}, milliseconds)` will fork the `function()` after `milliseconds` you have specified.

Now let's focus on the below snippet of code:

```
 const convertTime = consultDate + ' ' + consultTime;
 var d = new Date(convertTime);
 var ms = d.getTime();
 var milliLess15 = ms - (15 * 60 * 1000);
```

Let's say your appointment is at 12:00 pm today (in millisec let's say 1492776423) and current execution time is 10:00 am (in millisec 1485576423). By your logic, you are calling the `function()` after: `var milliLess15 = ms - (15 * 60 * 1000)` which is `1492776423 - (15 * 60 * 1000) = 1491876423`. Note here that, you **don't want to call `function()` after 1491876423 millisec**. Rather you want to call it after millisec equivalent of `12:00 - 10:00 - 00:15`. So your logic should look something like:

```
const convertTime = consultDate + ' ' + consultTime;
var d = new Date(convertTime);
var ms = d.getTime();
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentTimeMilli = currentTime.getTime();
var milliLess15 = ms - (15 * 60 * 1000) - currentTimeMilli;
```

Rest of the code will remain the same. Hope this answer helps you!